# Constant variable value on a recursive function

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

```
static boolean isPrime(int num){
    int consNum = num; //something like having a non-changing value 

    if(consNum < 2){
        return false;
    }

    else if( consNum % Math.round(num--/2) == 0 && num > 2)
        return false;
    }

    else{
        if(num==1)
            return true;
        else
            return isPrime(num);
    }

}
```

I'm trying to create a function that will determine if `num` is a prime number. Problem, i want a value(`consNum`) to stay with that value during the first call, Is there a way to do this recursively?

**Edit**

from:

```
if( (consNum % (int)(num--/2) + 0.5 == 0 )
```

to:

```
if( (consNum % Math.round(num--/2) == 0 && num > 2)
```

Comment: Side comment: the readability of `consNum%(int)((num--/2)+0.5)==0` is *really* low (and probably doesn't do what you expect it to anyway). I would strongly advise you to rewrite that...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Local variables are local to the invocation of the particular method;
>   recursive methods are no exception.

If you wish to pass that value down the invocation chain, you need to make a second parameter for it, and pass it down explicitly:

```
// Users of your code invoke this method
public static boolean isPrime(int num) {
    return isPrime(num, num);
}
// This overload with two parameters is the actual recursive method
private static boolean isPrime(int num, int original) {
    if(original%(int)((num--/2)+0.5)==0)
        return false;
    }

    else{
        if(num==1)
            return true;
        else
            return isPrime(num, original);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
    static boolean isFirst=true;
    static int consNum;
    static boolean isPrime(int num){

    if(isFirst){ // This condition will help you to keep consNum with the initial value
        consNum=num;
        isFirst=false;
    }

    if(consNum%(int)((num--/2)+0.5)==0)
        return false;
    }

    else{
        if(num==1)
            return true;
        else
            return isPrime(num);
    }

}
```

Comment: You may want to note that the method is now non-reentrant, meaning that you cannot call it from multiple threads.